# Mongodb text index - better scoring?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an index in MongoDB which covers name and email.
This works, and I can query it with:

```
const c = await Contact.
      find({ $text: { $search: search } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.skip(skip)
.limit(20);
```

But, the results are somewhat odd, yet logical.

e.g.

if I search for **"Roger Johan"**
It will start listing both people called Roger and Johan, which is logical.
*but*, it would have been less odd if it ranked **"Roger Johansson"** highest as that is a match on both **Roger** and **Johan%**

Is there any way to tune this?

I know I can regex match on partial, but that instead fails on things like: 
data: Roger T. Johansson
query: Roger Johansson

Is there any fancy trick to combine parts of these two options?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply search by phrase it will be able to find **Roger Johan**, but it won't work if you will try to search for **Rog** or **Johan**.

To make it work with partial matches on the first word we created additional field with prefixes for the word, i.g. `["Rog", "Roge"]` and included this field into text index.

Having that implemented search will be able to find searches for **Rog** as well as **Roger Johan**.

If you need to search last name **Johan** you can also include another property with prefixes `["Joh", "Joha", "Johan", "Johans", "Johanss", "Johansso"]` and give it lower (or higher, depending on how you want results to appear) rank. Or you can include all prefixes to the same array property if the rank should be same.

Just to be clear, you do need to use phrase search, i.e.: `"\"Roger Johan"\"`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself, but maybe you need to do the search as a phrase: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases

If not I think it will split your search term and then search.